# using istringstream, string to fill to vectors but List2 vector isn't filling, Probably error at iss.str(s); but why?

Tags: vector, iterator, istringstream

My code in `file.cpp`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile("minimum_scalar_product.in");
    ofstream outfile("min_scalar.out");
    string s;
    getline(infile,s);
    unsigned int testcase=atoi(s.c_str());
    for(int k=0;k<testcase;++k)
    {
        getline(infile,s);
        unsigned int n=atoi(s.c_str());
        long long value, result=0;
        vector<long long> List1, List2;
        vector<long long>::iterator it,it1;
        getline(infile,s);
        istringstream iss(s);
        while(iss>>value)
        {
            List1.push_back(value);
        }
        sort(List1.begin(),List1.end());
        for(it=List1.begin();it!=List1.end();++it)
        {
            cout<<*it<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        getline(infile,s);
        iss.str(s);
        while(iss>>value)
        {
            List2.push_back(value);
        }
        sort(List2.begin(),List2.end(),greater<long long>());
        for(it1=List2.begin();it1!=List2.end();++it1)
        {
            cout<<*it1<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        if(List1.size()==List2.size())
        {
            for(it=List1.begin(),it1=List2.begin();it!=List1.end();++it,++it1)
            {
                result+=((*it)*(*it1));
            }
        }
        else
        cout<<"\n not equal length\n";
        outfile<<"Case #"<<k+1<<": "<<result<<"\n";
    }
    infile.close();
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Input from `.in` file:

```
1000
3
1 -5 3
-2 1 4
5
5 4 3 1 2
1 1 0 1 0
7
677 463 -569 516 401 -998 882
890 588 959 909 948 -617 -655
8
-912 937 167 366 -222 -397 190 -216
354 -222 28 -236 75 869 -622 -56
```

The first line is no. of cases I have to solve. Next three lines are no. of elements and two elements lists respectively. I want to read elements in two lists and store in Vectors List1, List2. I used istringstream variable 'iss' to convert string to stream and store individual elements in vectors. The first time it works but second time it is not working.

output:

```
-5 1 3


 not equal length
1 2 3 4 5


 not equal length
-998 -569 401 463 516 677 882


 not equal length
-912 -397 -222 -216 167 190 366 937
```

expected output:

```
-5 1 3
-2 1 4

1 2 3 4 5
1 1 0 1 0

-998 -569 401 463 516 677 882
890 588 959 909 948 -617 -655

-912 -397 -222 -216 167 190 366 937
354 -222 28 -236 75 869 -622 -56

-741 -378 160 176
-665 -149 744 497
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm just trying to multiply all elements of List1 and List2, index to index and add them

Comment: `for(;it!=List1.end();++it,++it1)` -- Unless `List2.size()` <= `List1.size()`, this isn't going to work.

Comment: I know they are equal

Comment: *I know they are equal* -- And that type of reasoning is why bugs exist.  Actually write code to *confirm* that you're not going out of bounds.  We have no idea if they are equal or not, and you're asking us why you're getting crashes.  We report what we see.

Comment: I have the file that i'm reading from, it is a rule that they have to be equal, so I can arrange them and multiply. I checked the file too, my guess was also the same first time

Comment: what can I do to check if my Lists are storing more than they should?

Comment: `for(;it!=List1.end();++it,++it1)` could easily have just been `for(;it!=List1.end() && it1 != List2.end();++it,++it1)`.  Never write code hoping the data "fits the code".  You should always have checks to confirm that the data actually fits the code you're writing.  Another example is if the two lists are supposed to be the same size right after reading the data  -- put in an `assert(List1.size() == List2.size())` instead of assuming they are the same size.

Comment: thankyou so much, I just checked that and found out my second list isn't filling. probably something with    iss.str(s); is my guess. What's wrong here? Or why else is my List2 not filling

Comment: Now that you are showing us what you are getting as output for each input you need to clearly contrast that with what you expect to get as output for that input. You have to do some work in thinking about your questions if you want useful answers.

Comment: I want the second line of each case(line 4, 7, 10 of input) of list to be filled in List2, but its not filling so its not printing.

Comment: The output should be in two lines of sorted elements. and 'not equal length' shouldn't print